# java циклы Elements

Tags: java, for, jsoup

Не могу разложить элементы в БД каждый в свой столбец:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://some.site/").get();
Elements one = doc.getElementsByClass("selection-name");
Elements two = doc.getElementsByClass("value_one");
Elements thee = doc.getElementsByClass("some_count");


    for (Element name : one.subList(0, Math.min(10, one.size()))) {
        RatingDb ratingDb = new RatingDb();
        ratingDb.setName(name.text());
        for (Element rats : two.subList(0, Math.min(10, two.size()))) {
            ratingDb.setRating(rats.text());
            for (Element look : three.subList(0, Math.min(10, three.size()))) {
                ratingDb.setLook(look.text());
            }
        }
        ratingRepo.save(ratingDb);
    }
```

Беда прям с этими циклами. Работает только `Element name`, остальные заполняются последними значениями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "остальные заполняются последними значениями" - а надо что?

Comment: Должно быть как красным шрифтом, а подставляется только последняя 3.

Comment: Задача схожа с инсертом в БД элементов массива или коллекции.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Я уже поставил минус.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Коряво, за то сам)

```
    Elements names = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
    Elements rating = doc.getElementsByClass("tag-count badge badge-info");

    for (int i = 0, namesSize = names.size(); i < namesSize; i++) {
        Element name = names.get(i);
        RatingDb ratingDb = new RatingDb();
        ratingDb.setName(name.text());
        for (int j = i, ratingSize = rating.size(); j < ratingSize;) {
            Element rats = rating.get(j);
            ratingDb.setRating(rats.text());

            ratingRepo.save(ratingDb);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Element name : one.subList(0, Math.min(10, one.size()))) {
    for (Element rats : two.subList(0, Math.min(10, two.size()))) {
        for (Element look : three.subList(0, Math.min(10, three.size()))) {
            RatingDb ratingDb = new RatingDb(); // <--- !!!
            ratingDb.setName(name.text());   
            ratingDb.setRating(rats.text());
            ratingDb.setLook(look.text());
            ratingRepo.save(ratingDb);          // <--- !!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kent Сейчас я догадаюсь, что Вам надо.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]